# Get stack trace in Java

Tags: java, stack-trace

How do I get the exception stack trace in Java?
I can use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().but get error linenumber

Correctly:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at me.edagarli.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

Wrongly:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)    
me.edagarli.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Comment: What type of program are you running?  A console application, a web application, Android, something else?

Comment: please show the code of your Main class and the input that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getFullErrorDescription(Exception exceptionObj ) {
    String textmsg = "";

    if (exceptionObj != null) {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = exceptionObj.getStackTrace();
        textmsg += "\nIn File : " + ste[index].getClassName() + " ";
        textmsg += "\nIn Method : " + ste[index].getMethodName() + "() ";
        textmsg += "\nAt Line :" + ste[index].getLineNumber() + " ";
    }
    System.err.println(textmsg);
    return textmsg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have stacktrace messages into String instance you can use:

```
    public String getStackTraceAsString(Exception ex){
    StackTraceElement[] elements = ex.getStackTrace();
    String stacktraceMessage = "";

    for(StackTraceElement element : elements){
        stacktraceMessage += "\nIn File : " + element.getClassName() + " ";
        stacktraceMessage += "\nIn Method : " + element.getMethodName() + " ";
        stacktraceMessage += "\nAt Line :" + element.getLineNumber() + " ";
    }

    return stacktraceMessage;
}
```

If you need only print stacktrace you can use printStackTrace method:

```
try{
    int a = 100 / 0;
}catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```